# Pandas replaces cell value with predefined value

Tags: pandas

My df:

```
Name    Height        Weight
Anay       5.8          65.5
Vij        $$           70
Kane       4.5          ,,
Nancy       k           80.0
```

I would like to fill invalid data in Height column with 5.2 and Weight column with 60. Is there any way to do this? (I know with fillna we can fill with predetermined value but fillna is not applicable here!)

Expected output:

```
Name    Height        Weight
Anay       5.8          65.5
Vij        5.2           70
Kane       4.5          60
Nancy      5.2           80.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) before [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Height'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Height'], errors='coerce').fillna(5.2)
df['Weight'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Weight'], errors='coerce').fillna(60)
```